# .NET Core 2 WebAPI CORS problems with Angular 4 front end and Windows Auth

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

Yes I have countless articles and re-arranged add app.UserCors and other pieces of advice but am still stuck.

Using Visual Studio WebAPI Core 2 with Angular 2 web front end.

Using Windows authentication on remote server using IIS 8.5 (actually this doesn't work locally either).

WebAPI startup conf:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeDB")));

    //////// ********************
    //////// Setup CORS
    //////// ********************
    var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
    corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
    corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
    corsBuilder.WithOrigins("*"); 
    corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", corsBuilder.Build());
    });

    services.AddMvc();

...


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("AllowAll"); //<===            

    app.UseMvc();

...
```

*When I run the WebAPI locally, or deploy it to a remote server, My Angular 4 front end gives me:*

For a call to a WebAPI controller - **401 (Unauthorized)** (even on controllers that have no `[Authorize()]` set.

*When I try to use my local instance of the Angular app to access the remote WebAPI:*

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:62482' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I have tried re-arranged the order of adding services in startup.

I have manually added the respone headers in IIS8.5 (they get overwritten whenever I deploy new code).

I have remove all the CORS stuff completely from the WebAPI app.

I *SWEAR* this all worked at one time.  Not sure what changed.

I all runs fine when I deploy both the WebAPI Core 2 app and the Angular web app to the remote server because origins are the same, but that makes local debugging impossible.

*** Angular REPO code per request:

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DocumentModel } from '../models/document.model';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { IRepository } from './IRepository';
declare var API_URL: string;

@Injectable()
export class DocumentRepository implements IRepository<DocumentModel, number> {
    GetByDocument(key: any): Observable<DocumentModel[]> {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    private httpService: Http;
    private apiRootUrl: string;

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.httpService = http;
        this.apiRootUrl = API_URL;
    }

    Create(Model: DocumentModel): Observable<any> {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }

    Find(key: any): Observable<DocumentModel[]> {
        return this.httpService.get(this.apiRootUrl +'documents/mine').map(result => result.json());
    }

    Get(id: any): Observable<DocumentModel> {
        return this.httpService.get(this.apiRootUrl +'documents/' + id).map(result => result.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your .net core api always getting served on the same port ie..62482 
also can you try adding this in your configure function `app.UseCors(builder =>
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost")
           .AllowAnyHeader()
    );`

and post your angular setup also ... @user3637002

Comment: Please also show the Angular 2 code that makes the API call (including CORS headers / setup).

Comment: Change, `WithOrigins("*")` to `AllowAnyOrigin`. And try adding it to your controller manually to test it out with the attribute `[EnableCors("AllowAll")]`

Comment: >>Change, WithOrigins("*") to AllowAnyOrigin. And try adding it to your controller manually to test it out with the attribute [EnableCors("AllowAll")]>> Tried all that already... no dice.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :
In Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors(
            options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader()
                                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                                               .AllowCredentials()
        );
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

and that all, no other mention to Cors.

I use JWT Bearer Token and [Authorize] works as intended.

You can try with Postman first, just to see if your endpoint is working, then move to make an Angular http.get()

This is the angular part

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().
                    set('Accept', 'application/json')

const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/'  

return this.http.get(
   url + 'endpoint',
   { headers: headers }
);
```

Comment: Do I need any auth in my Angular app at all?  The API uses windows authentication and seems to work fine on the server for detecting the users identity.  It is only when running locally and trying to access a remote server do I have these problems.

Comment: FYI  SWAGGER *always* works when I use it to test the API.  This seems to be an angular web app issue.